# GLSL Border Shader

Tags: ios, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I'm attempting to write a shader to put a border around text. It compiles and runs ok, but the border is grainy and aliased. Any suggestions for making it better please?

[image: Shader]

This is the **first shader I have written** so don't have much knowledge about the API. Could any example code be commented please? I don't want to just copy and paste an answer; I'd like to understand it.

Additionally, I have a problem when I make the text smaller which is best explained by this image. Any suggestions on fixing this too please?

[image: Shader]

The edge detection could be better too. So far I take advantage of the fact that the antialiased texture I use for input has edges with `0.0 < alpha < 1.0`

So far I have this:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec4 u_borderColor;
uniform float u_width;
uniform float u_height;

void main()
{
    mediump vec4 total = vec4(0.0);

    float alpha = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a; 
    //If somewhere between complete transparent and completely opaque
    if (alpha > 0.0 && alpha < 1.0)
    {
        total.rgb = u_borderColor.rgb;
        total.a *= u_borderColor.a;
        gl_FragColor = u_borderColor;
    }
    else
    {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why aren't you setting the value of gl_FragColor to total? Alpha is no more maintained correctly....

Next, total.a = 1 - alpha;  (from outer to inner)

or a variant like:

total.a = abs(0.5 - alpha); (blend both sides)

would probably make more sense, when blending.

Comment: This has produced better results but still isn't useable for the smaller text. Any suggestions for better edge detection please?

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as correct because it pointed out a flaw with my code. It should be noted to future viewers however, that it didn't solve all of the issues raised in the question. I haven't found a perfect solution yet.

Comment: For a smaller scale, you have to pass another varying float scale; and multiply the alpha above with it ... total.a = scale*(0.5 - alpha) etc. scale shrinks as size of text shrinks, so it'll yield a smaller region with pink etc. Just experiment with it till you get a good solution! :)

Comment: 1. In reality, for bitmap fonts, 2D decent edge detection is performed thru' morphology. Perfect edge detection is performed by connected components. 2. Since none of them are real time, go with this approach: If you are rendering text thru' vertices, pass a vertex shader which looks at the silhouette edges of the font and emits a color changes based on the parameter. Then the pixel shader takes that input and blends. It's similar to a Cel Shading system.

Answer (score 0):

In the code i see that your setting `gl_FragColor = u_borderColor` which is `(0,0,0,0)` from total if alpha is `>0 <1`. Firstly change your total to some other contrast color and your code work on for a image. but text has different bends which makes it grainy so need to change it the  rendering which cannot be said without code.
Do suggest if i am wrong
Thank you